# Clearing tasks when starting a new task from service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I have a serious problem, I have to start/control activities via service, and for activities I use local broadcast messages to update the UI. When I send a broadcast message, it is received by lots of receivers, but I only want to get it received by the topmost activity.

I tried to unregister the previous activity's receivers, but it's simply not working. (There is a screen manager that keeps track of current/topmost activity and also the previous activity.)

So, is there something good solution to close task instances of the task, ad only one instance running in the foreground? Or some working method to unregister receivers? (I tried lots of stuff, but not working on Android 2.2).

Comment: Seems to me that you need to get the "unregister of previous activity's receivers" working. That should solve the problem. Please post the code you use to register and unregister and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Either you can unregister your other receivers (good practice, would save some resources), or used an ordered broadcast and change the priorities dynamically.

Comment: Thank you the notofications, I tried unregister them in the onPause() and onDestroy() function, but it simply didn't work. It keeps receive multiple times the messages and even more and more have after screen changes. Could somebody recommend somebody a good pattern/method for that?
It could be working if I don't start the activities as a new task...